# How to wire up a Sennheiser MKE-2 for use with Lectrosonics SMV Transmitters

Tags: lectrosonics, sennheiser

I purchased my Lectrosonics SMV's a while back but had immense issues trying to get them to work with my Sennheiser MKE2 Microphones and the M150's that I purchased with the lectro's simply did not come close to the quality of sound that the Sennheiser's gave me.

The local (I'm based in Johannesburg, South Africa) Sennheiser and Lectrosonics agents could not help me, nor give me the time of day as to how to wire the mics up correctly.
The Sennheiser agnets couldn't even tell me that the microphone was a positive bias 2-wire electret!  When I asked them if it was, their answer was "Um...I dont know"

Answer (score 2):

**THE OP HAD ANSWERED THE QUESTION IN HIS QUESTION... JUST MOVING TO AN ANSWER.  CREDIT GOES TO @AndreFeldmann**

---

To cut a long story short, I finally found an electronics engineer who specialises in Sennheiser products and he was able to give me the correct configuration!  See the diagram 
below!

[image]

Comment: I have also some smq and smqv transmitters and Mke2 lavaliers, but when I touch the cable of lav apears noise ( seem to be to sesitivy) do you have experince that problem ? As you know cable has 3 wires one red color , one blue color and shield , i connected shield and blue to pin 1, red to pin 3 , and pint 2 to pin 4 , i have also m152 lav lectrosonics iit has not that nosie , could you please let me know email fron the sennheiser engeenier and email as well,
Any help will be apreciated Jsoe luis martinez
Jluismtz8@prodigy.net.mx
Mexico df.